# 2 Python Classes 1 File -> CustomTkinter Image cannot be loaded

Tags: python, image, tkinter, customtkinter

In case of a project for our university, we tried to create an Adblocker. My Task is to create a UI for our blocking software. Therefore, I'm using the Customtkinter library.

I created 2 Classes, the first is the UI itself, the second one the welcome page. On the welcome page, the user has to insert the IP Address of the database our project needs.

How it works:

→ User starts the application → Welcome page appears → User enters IP → UI appears.

Because I didn't find another solution, I created a normal CTK Window for both classes.

```
class UserInterface(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("600x600")
        self.title("CTk example")
```

```
class Welcomepage(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("384x308")
        self.title("Welcome")
```

Both are defined in the `Application.py` located in the main folder of the project.

I also want to use images, so I created the folder `images` where all images are located and `images.py` also located in this folder.

`Images.py` just defines all images:

```
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image


# Menu-bar Image:
logo_ui = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("images\yblocker.png"), dark_image=Image.open("images\yblocker.png"),size=(128,128))

# Welcomepage Image:
logo_welcome = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("images\yblocker.png"), dark_image=Image.open("images\yblocker.png"),size=(128,128))
```

Now I want to create a label with an Image in both classes:

```
import images.image as images

class UserInterface(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("600x600")
        self.title("CTk example")

        # Initalizing Menu-bar:
        self.menu = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=150, height=600, border_width=1, border_color="#1F538D")
        self.menu.place(x=0,y=0)

        # --> Initalizing Elements of the Menu-bar:

        # Image-label:
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.menu, image= images.logo_ui, text="")
        self.logo_label.place(x=11,y=10)

class Welcomepage(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("384x308")
        self.title("Welcome")
       
        self.image_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, width=128,text="", image= images.logo_welcome)
        self.image_label.place(x=128,y=0)
```

So using the image in class User interface works without any Problems (the image is visible), using the same way to show the image in class Welcomepage following Error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Path to Application.py", line 490, in <module>
    welcome = Welcomepage()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Path to Application.py", line 432, in __init__
    self.image_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, width=128,text="", image= images.logo_welcome)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_label.py", line 104, in __init__
    self._update_image()
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_label.py", line 141, in _update_image
    self._label.configure(image=self._image.create_scaled_photo_image(self._get_widget_scaling(),
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1716, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1706, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage11" doesn't exist
```

`Application.py`:

```py
import images.image as images
import customtkinter

class UserInterface(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("600x600")
        self.title("CTk example")

        # Initalizing Menu-bar:
        self.menu = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=150, height=600, border_width=1, border_color="#1F538D")
        self.menu.place(x=0,y=0)

        # Image:
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.menu, image= images.logo_ui, text="")
        self.logo_label.place(x=11,y=10)


class Welcomepage(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("384x308")
        self.title("Welcome")
       
        self.image_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, width=128,text="", image= images.logo_welcome)
        self.image_label.place(x=128,y=0)

        self.start_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, width=50, text="Start", command = self.start_button_action)
        self.start_button.place(x=233,y=230)

    def start_button_action(self):
        ui.mainloop()

ui = UserInterface()

wp = Welcomepage()
wp.mainloop()
```

[Here is the whole problem as a zip file (including the pictures)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asmcio125q7d1yQgqL8iJCcFyav9?e=BAfmPe)

So now my Question is why? I already don't understand why he's talking from "pyimage11"

- First thing I tried was to use exactly the same image, but that changed nothing
- Then I tried to configure the labels with the images in `Images.py` by first importing `application.py` and then configuring the respective element with `.configure(image=)`. However, I had the problem that I naturally imported in a circle, as I have to start a function in `welcomepage` to do the configuration in `image.py`
- with the help of AI, I tried other things, but surprisingly none of them worked...

Comment: Did your program print anything else, maybe an error message about loading the image file? Does `open("images\yblocker.png", "rb").read()` succeed (if not, then the image file is missing or the filename is wrong)?

Comment: It's harmless in your code, but in general, to avoid `\n` etc., escape backslashes in pathnames like: `"images\\yblocker.png"` or `r"images\yblocker.png"`.

Comment: `Import images.image as images` starting with a capital `I` produces a SyntaxError. Surely you don't have it like that in your .py source file. Please copy-paste the full source file (which is small but complete), not just random snippets, so that others can run it to reproduce your results.

Comment: Please upload more LOCs', and if you can add a file tree or list of files

Comment: Thanks for that lemme take some time to take a look at it.

Comment: The error is mostly caused by multiple instances of `Tk()` which `CTk()` inherits from.

Comment: @acw1668 right on point. I too said the same thing and added a code for his convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Description:

So the issue is caused by instantiating 2 Different Classes creating 2 `CTk Window`. I have modified the `UserInterface` Class to instantiate a `CTkTopLevel` instead of a `CTk Window`.

### Solution:

Replace your `Application.py` code with this code:

```py
import images.image as images
import customtkinter

class UserInterface(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("600x600")
        self.title("CTk example")

        # Initalizing Menu-bar:
        self.menu = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=150, height=600, border_width=1, border_color="#1F538D")
        self.menu.place(x=0, y=0)

        # Image:
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.menu, image=images.logo_ui, text="")
        self.logo_label.place(x=11, y=10)
        
class Welcomepage(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("384x308")
        self.title("Welcome")
        
        self.image_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, image=images.logo_welcome, text="")
        self.image_label.place(x=128, y=0)

        self.start_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, width=50, text="Start", command=self.start_button_action)
        self.start_button.place(x=233, y=230)
        
        self.toplevel_window = None

    def start_button_action(self):
        self.toplevel_window = UserInterface(self)

wp = Welcomepage()
wp.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already had an idea in this direction, but so far it had failed because of the implementation, since a TopLevel is normally called directly :)

Comment: No problem hit me up if you want help if anything else